# What does double dot (..) in Julia Programming Language mean?

Tags: julia

For example in the code below, x is defining the domain, but why is there the double dot between 0 and 4pi?

```
using ApproxFun
x=Fun(identity,0..4π)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`..` is not part of Julia, rather part of the packages used by `ApproxFun`.

It is used to represent intervals, see the code below

```
julia> u = 1..3
1..3

julia> dump(u)
Interval{:closed,:closed,Int64}
  left: Int64 1
  right: Int64 3
```

So this is just a convenience constructor for the `Interval` object, see:

```
julia> 1..3 === Interval{:closed,:closed,Int64}(1,3)
true
```

Answer (score 9):

`..` is an operator (like e.g. `+`) but it does not have a default definition. You can define it to to whatever you want:

```
julia> ..(a, b) = println(a, ", ", b)
.. (generic function with 1 method)

julia> "hello" .. "world"
hello, world
```

The Julia package [IntervalArithmetic](https://juliaintervals.github.io/IntervalArithmetic.jl/stable/) uses it to construct an interval, e.g.

```
julia> using IntervalArithmetic

julia> 4..5
[4, 5]

julia> typeof(4..5)
Interval{Float64}
```

and I suspect this is what it is used for in your code example.